# How to connect to virtual machine which is considered as the main host server?

Tags: openbmc

I am running openBmc Romulus image on QEMU as given in the tutorials. I want to connect it to another virtual machine which will act as the host complex(main server). So that I can turn it on/off from the BMC session and try various other things.

Answer (score 0):

No one has done this yet to my knowledge.

Comment: Can you suggest any method to do this?